# Script for run script

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wsh

I have a script on vbscript

```
Dim WSHShell, WinDir, Value, wshProcEnv, fso, Spath    

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    


Dim objFSO, objFileCopy    
Dim strFilePath, strDestination    

 Const OverwriteExisting = True    
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
 Set windir = objFSO.getspecialfolder(0)    
 objFSO.CopyFile "\\dv.rt.ru\SYSVOL\DV.RT.RU\scripts\shutdown.vbs", windir&"\", OverwriteExisting    

strComputer = "."    
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _    
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _    
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")     
JobID = "1"    

Set colScheduledJobs = objWMIService.ExecQuery _    
    ("Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob")    
For Each objJob in colScheduledJobs    
 objJob.Delete    
Next    

Set objNewJob = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob")    
errJobCreate = objNewJob.Create _    
    (windir & "\shutdown.vbs", "********093000.000000+660", _    
        True, 1 OR 2 OR 4 OR 8 OR 16 OR 32 OR 64, ,True, JobId)
```

How make that shutdown.vbs not run once at 9:30 but run for 9:30 to 12:00

Comment: please find the code formatting, or click the question mark for help.

Comment: Crossposted here: [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/142869/script-for-run-script-on-vbs), [ServerFault (closed)](http://serverfault.com/questions/141357/script-for-run-script-closed) and [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/142355/script-for-run-script-on-vbs).

Comment: I don't understand your question "How make that shutdown.vbs not run once at 9:30 but run for 9:30 to 12:00." Could you please elaborate a little? marc

Answer (score 0):

- Modify your shutdown.vbs script to check the time - if it's between 9:30 and 12:00, shutdown
- Schedule two tasks to execute the shutdown script: one that runs at 9:30 and one that runs on system startup.